# Configure system date with configuration file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, configuration-files

if i want to setup the date of the database with a configuration file... how can i achieve this?
So for example if the configuration file says it is 12/12/12 getdate() retrieves that date...

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. getdate() retrieves the current system time of the server that sql is running on.

Comment: Well how can I set the current system time with a configuration file?

Comment: You don't through sql. The current system time is the time that is set in windows. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thank you Sean! Well, i have a school project. Where i have to build a app with its own DB. One of the requirements is that the system date can set up with a configuration file. I already made lots of getdate() in the script so I was wondering if I can avoid removing the getdate()'s. Because if not, i have to send them from the front end.